# How to do a conditional statement in SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-like

What I'm trying to do is when `@aValue` parameter is like 'abc%' then run

```
select 
    f.name, f.amount, f.date 
from 
    fakeTable f
where f.name like @aValue
    and f.date > '01/01/2000'
```

Otherwise if the `@aValue` param is not like 'abc%', then select all the records where the f.name is equal to @aValue.

```
select 
        f.name, f.amount, f.date 
    from 
        fakeTable f
    where f.name = @aValue
        and f.date > '01/01/2000'
```

I'm trying to accomplish this using a CASE statement within my Where. In my where statement I'm getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near LIKE

My query:

```
Declare @aValue varchar(5) = 'abcde';
-- @aValue = 'xyz';

select 
    f.name, f.amount, f.date 
from 
    fakeTable f
where 
    f.name = case 
                 when @aValue 'abc%' 
                     then f.name like @aValue
                 else f.name = @aValue
             end
    and f.date > '01/01/2000'
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing the syntax error?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please clean-up your shown code. Your `when` does not contain a proper boolean expression and you have dunned `,` (comma) before `end`.

Comment: Your case expression appears to be malformed, it's better to use logical and/or to give the optimizer the best chance of using an index.

Comment: `f.name = 'abcdev'` is identical to `f.name = 'abcdef'`. Is the actual logic here "If `@aValue` starts with string `abc` then you want the WHERE condition to be `WHERE f.name LIKE 'abc%'` otherwise you want `f.name = @aValue`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code attempt is product specific.

Comment: @JNevill yes you are correct. that's what I'm trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `CASE` expression, use the `OR` and `AND` operators like this:

```
WHERE (
        (@aValue LIKE 'abc%' AND f.name LIKE @aValue) 
        OR 
        (@aValue NOT LIKE 'abc%' AND f.name = @aValue)
      )
  AND f.date > '01/01/2000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to juggle conditions in a CASE Expression you can do this with boolean logic:

```
WHERE 
   (
      f.name = @aValue
      OR
      (
          @aValue LIKE 'abc%'
          AND
          f.name LIKE 'abc%'
      )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `union` and a query for each case, this is often better than trying to combine multiple criteria which can prevent efficent index usage.

Something along the lines of the following, the first test on @value being true should mean only one or other of the queries actually executes.

```
select <columns>
from table
where @value like 'abc%' and name like @value+'%'

union all

select <columns>
from table
where @value not like 'abc%' and name = @value
```